# Serialize & Deserialize C# user Defined Classes in .Net

Tags: c#, object, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I m working with Core Web API and I have the challenge to nest different class objects into an **ArrayList** and send them over the `FromBody` object, the issue is I have to pack them in a way that on the receiving side I deserialize them into their respective objects.
an example is below.

```
[Serializable]
public class M1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class M2 : M1
{
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        M1 mObj = new M1();
        M2 m2Obj = new M2();
        ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
        mObj.Name = "Apple";
        mObj.Age = 20;
        m2Obj.Name = "Banana";
        m2Obj.Age = 30;
        m2Obj.Gender = "Male";
        m2Obj.Height = 6;
        alist.Add(mObj);
        alist.Add(m2Obj);
        string result = string.Empty;
        M1 mObjD = new M1();
        M2 mObj2D = new M2();
    
        //Method1                
        try
        {
            result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alist, Formatting.Indented);
            mObjD = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M1>(result);
            mObj2D = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M2>(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    
        //Method 2
        try
        {
            result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mObj, Formatting.Indented);
            result = result + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(m2Obj, Formatting.Indented);
            mObjD = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M1>(result);
            mObj2D = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M2>(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

For the first method its throwing error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'SerliazeDeserliaze.M1' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array of a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

for the second method, it says

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 4, position 2.

Comment: You are serializing arraylist in to result variable. Then you are trying to deserialize result to single object of class. That's not valid you can't do it.. array json string can not be deserialized to a single object.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in this code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have two major class objects and want to send them in a single body parameter, on the receiving side I could put them back into their respective objects.

Comment: How the receiving end expect the objects to be passed? You can create a wrapper class with properties of type M1 and M2. And serialize it and send it. The receiving end will get json object string and deserialize it to the same structure there

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya good idea, I was playing this way, alternatively, I can go for another solution is to convert the JSON to DataSet and then readback in respective tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you serialize list of object, you should deserialize it also into list:

```
string result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aList, Formatting.Indented);
List<M1> mObjD = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<M1>>(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**JSON supports the following two data structures**,

Collection of name/value pairs - This Data Structure is supported by different programming languages.
Ordered list of values - It includes an array, list, vector or sequence, etc.
JSON has the following styles,

**Object**
An unordered "name/value" assembly. An object begins with "{" and ends with "}". Behind each "name", there is a colon. And comma is used to separate much "name/value". For example,

```
var user = {"name":"Manas","gender":"Male","birthday":"1987-8-8"}
```

**Array**
Value order set. An array begins with "[" and end with "]". And values are separated with commas. For example,

```
var userlist = [{"user":{"name":"Manas","gender":"Male","birthday":"1987-8-8"}},
    {"user":{"name":"Mohapatra","Male":"Female","birthday":"1987-7-7"}}]
```

**String**
Any quantity Unicode character assembly which is enclosed with quotation marks. It uses backslash to escape.

```
var userlist = "{\"ID\":1,\"Name\":\"Manas\",\"Address\":\"India\"}"
```

```
We can implement JSON Serialization/Deserialization in the following three ways:
```

- Using `JavaScriptSerializer` class
- Using `DataContractJsonSerializer` class
- Using JSON.NET library
- Using `DataContractJsonSerializer`

  - DataContractJsonSerializer class helps to serialize and deserialize JSON.
  - It is present in namespace `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` which is
    available in assembly `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll`. Using the
    class we can serialize an object into JSON data and deserialize JSON
    data into an object.

Let's say there is Employee class with properties such as name, address, and property values also assigned. Now we can convert the Employee class instance to the JSON document. This JSON document can be deserialized into the Employee class or another class with an equivalent data contract. The following code snippets demonstrate about serialization and deserialization.

Let's create a custom class BlogSite for serialization and deserialization,

```
[DataContract]
class BlogSite
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

C# Serialization

In Serialization, it converts a custom .Net object to a JSON string. In the following code, it creates an instance of BlogSiteclass and assigns values to its properties. Then we create an instance of DataContractJsonSerializer class by passing the parameter BlogSite class and create an instance of MemoryStream class to write object(BlogSite). Lastly it creates an instance of StreamReader class to read JSON data from MemorySteam object.

```
BlogSite bsObj = new BlogSite()
{
    Name = "C-sharpcorner",
    Description = "Share Knowledge"
};

DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BlogSite));
MemoryStream msObj = new MemoryStream();
js.WriteObject(msObj, bsObj);
msObj.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(msObj);

// "{\"Description\":\"Share Knowledge\",\"Name\":\"C-sharpcorner\"}"
string json = sr.ReadToEnd();

sr.Close();
msObj.Close();
```

C# Deserialization

In Deserialization, it does the opposite of Serialization, which means it converts JSON string to a custom .Net object. In the following code, it creates an instance of BlogSite class and assigns values to its properties. Then we create an instance of DataContractJsonSerializer class by passing the parameter BlogSite class and creating an instance of MemoryStream class to write an object(BlogSite). Lastly, it creates an instance of StreamReader class to read JSON data from MemorySteam object.

```
string json = "{\"Description\":\"Share Knowledge\",\"Name\":\"C-sharpcorner\"}";

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
{
   // Deserialization from JSON
   DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BlogSite));
   BlogSite bsObj2 = (BlogSite)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
   Response.Write("Name: " + bsObj2.Name); // Name: C-sharpcorner
   Response.Write("Description: " + bsObj2.Description); // Description: Share Knowledge
}
```

C# Using JavaScriptJsonSerializer

JavaScriptSerializer is a class that helps to serialize and deserialize JSON. It is present in the namespace System.Web.Script.Serialization is available in assembly System.Web.Extensions.dll. To serialize a .Net object to JSON string use the Serialize method. It's possible to deserialize JSON string to .Net object using Deserialize or DeserializeObject methods. Let's see how to implement serialization and deserialization using JavaScriptSerializer.

```
Following code, a snippet is to declare a custom class of BlogSites type.
```

```
class BlogSites
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

C# Serialization

In Serialization, it converts a custom .Net object to a JSON string. In the following code, it creates an instance of BlogSiteclass and assigns some values to its properties. Then we create an instance of JavaScriptSerializer and call Serialize() method by passing object(BlogSites). It returns JSON data in string format.

```
// Creating BlogSites object
BlogSites bsObj = new BlogSites()
{
   Name = "C-sharpcorner",
   Description = "Share Knowledge"
};

// Serializing object to json data
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonData = js.Serialize(bsObj); // {"Name":"C-sharpcorner","Description":"Share Knowledge"}
```

C# Deserialization

In Deserialization, it does the opposite of Serialization which means it converts JSON string to custom .Net object. In the following code, it creates a JavaScriptSerializer instance and calls Deserialize() by passing JSON data. It returns a custom object (BlogSites) from JSON data.

```
// Deserializing json data to object
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
BlogSites blogObject = js.Deserialize<BlogSites>(jsonData);
string name = blogObject.Name;
string description = blogObject.Description;

// Other way to whithout help of BlogSites class
dynamic blogObject = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);
string name = blogObject["Name"];
string description = blogObject["Description"];
```

C# Using Json.NET

Json.NET is a third-party library that helps conversion between JSON text and .NET object using the JsonSerializer. The JsonSerializer converts .NET objects into their JSON equivalent text and back again by mapping the .NET object property names to the JSON property names. It is open-source software and free for commercial purposes.

The following are some awesome features,

- Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON.
- LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON.
- High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers.
- Easy to read JSON.
- Convert JSON to and from XML.
- Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight and Windows Phone.

Let’s start learning how to install and implement:

In Visual Studio, go to Tools Menu -> Choose Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console. It opens a command window where we need to put the following command to install Newtonsoft.Json.

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

OR

In Visual Studio, Tools menu -> Manage Nuget Package Manager Solution and type “JSON.NET” to search it online. Here's the figure,

```
Json.NET

Serialization
```

In Serialization, it converts a custom .Net object to a JSON string. In the following code, it creates an instance of BlogSiteclass and assigns some values to its properties. Then it calls static method SerializeObject() of JsonConvert class by passing object(BlogSites). It returns JSON data in string format.

```
// Creating BlogSites object
BlogSites bsObj = new BlogSites()
{
    Name = "C-sharpcorner",
    Description = "Share Knowledge"
};

// Convert BlogSites object to JOSN string format
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bsObj);

Response.Write(jsonData);
```

C# Deserialization

In Deserialization, it does the opposite of Serialization which means it converts JSON string to custom .Net object. In the following code, it calls the static method DeserializeObject() of the JsonConvert class by passing JSON data. It returns a custom object (BlogSites) from JSON data.

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'C-sharpcorner',
  'Description': 'Share Knowledge'
}";
BlogSites bsObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BlogSites>(json);
Response.Write(bsObj.Name);
```

JSON.NET, visit here.
In Visual Studio, Tools menu -> Manage Nuget Package Manger Solution and type “JSON.NET” to search it online. Here's the

Comment: Well Aamir, I am ok, till the rest of the process, the challenge is when I have a list of different class objects in JSON string and I want to parse them into respective objects.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try to use the SO provided code formatting tools.

Answer (score 0):

By doing some hack I have done that different way.

```
M1 mObj = new M1();
M2 m2Obj = new M2();
ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
ArrayList alistb = new ArrayList();
mObj.Name = "Apple";
mObj.Age = 20;
m2Obj.Name = "Banana";
m2Obj.Age = 30;
m2Obj.Gender = "Male";
m2Obj.Height = 6;
alist.Add(mObj);
alist.Add(m2Obj);
string result = string.Empty;
M1 mObjD = new M1();
M2 mObj2D = new M2();

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alist, Formatting.Indented, new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(ArrayList)));
alistb= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ArrayList>(json, new KeysJsonConverter(typeof(ArrayList)));
mObjD = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M1>(alistb[0].ToString());
mObj2D = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<M2>(alistb[1].ToString());
```

Serializing the list into JSON and then Deserializing it in a reverse way get the job done.